# Select first element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement a navigation menu that has a block of UL > LI within it:

```
<aside id="nav-container" role="complementary" style="width: 232px;">
  <nav class="overview" id="primary-nav" role="nav" style="display: block;">
    <h3 class="section">
      <span class="menu-toggle"></span>
      <span>The Basics</span>
    </h3>
    <ul class="depth-1 shortcuts" style="display: none;">
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Introduction</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">A Chapter in the Zeitgeist Movement</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Getting Real with expectations</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Point of Focus in a chapter</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h3 class="section">
      <span class="menu-toggle"></span>
      <span>Setting up a National Chapter</span>
    </h3>
    <ul class="depth-1 shortcuts" style="display: none;">
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Gathering Volunteers &amp; Social Media</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Establishing a Website &amp; Tools</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Organising a Core Group</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Expanding into Regional Chapters</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h3 class="section">
      <span class="menu-toggle"></span>
      <span>Setting up a city or local Chapter</span>
    </h3>
    <ul class="depth-1 shortcuts" style="display: none;">
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Introduction</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Getting Started</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Raising Volunteers</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Organising a Core Group</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h3 class="section">
      <span class="menu-toggle"></span>
      <span>Organising Events</span>
    </h3>
    <ul class="depth-1 shortcuts" style="display: none;">
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Types of Events</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Finding a Space</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Gathering Materials</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Promoting the Event</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Executing the Event</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h3 class="section">
      <span class="menu-toggle"></span>
      <span>Organising Project Teams</span>
    </h3>
    <ul class="depth-1 shortcuts" style="display: none;">
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">“Your idea, your project” concept</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Guidelines</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Project Methodology</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Devising a Project Structure</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Organising Volunteers </a></li>
    </ul>
    <h3 class="section">
      <span class="menu-toggle"></span>
      <span>Appendix</span>
    </h3>
    <ul class="depth-1 shortcuts" style="display: none;">
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Tips from Coordinators</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Tips on DVDs</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</aside>
```

Initially all the   are closed, when I click on an h3, the ul list   turns to

I have this javascript code:

```
  // menu open close
  this.leftMenuToggle = function () {
    var leftMenuToggle = $( ".section" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      leftMenuToggle.toggleClass("active");
      leftMenuToggle.next().css('display', 'block');
      console.log('we clicked this menu item');
    });
  }
```

But it opens all the .section items, what is the correct way to alter my code so that if I click on  ...  it opens only the child ul list?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following way you can remove the hardcoded style from your lists and when you click the link the list toggles.

Javascript

```
$('#nav-container').on('click', '.section', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $shortcut = $(this).next();
    $('#nav-container ul.active').not($shortcut).removeClass('active');
    $shortcut.andSelf().toggleClass('active');
});
```

CSS

```
ul.active {
    display: block;
}

ul:not(.active) {
  display: none;
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/PzM4D/)

Comment: thanks, but how do you reset it on click, so that the ul list is hidden and the next item is open or when you click on the actual H3 link?

Comment: nope this did not work as expected as on clicking the section, the class active is removed, but the display block stays always to 'none'

Comment: @khinester Because you have to remove the style tag from it. Like I described on my answer.

Comment: by the way, how do you change the code, so that if you click on a menu and then click on another menu the previous menu items are closed?

Comment: @khinester Add `$('ul.active').removeClass('active');` after `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: thanks, one more question: how do you close the current active menu? http://jsfiddle.net/PzM4D/2/ as clicking on an open menu does not seem to close it!

Answer (score 0):

"this" refers to the clicked/current element in a jQuery handler.

```
$( ".section" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleClass("active").next("ul").css('display', 'block');
  console.log('we clicked this menu item');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
 $('#nav-container .overview h3.section').on("click", function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).toggleClass("active");

      $(this).next('#nav-container .overview ul.depth-1 shortcuts')..css('display', 'block');
 }
```

Why it works:
     Because $(this) referrs to the currently clicked element, while in your code:

```
 var leftMenuToggle
```

referrs to the result of the jquery selector, ie ALL the sections.

Answer (score 0):

Instead this:

```
leftMenuToggle.toggleClass("active");
leftMenuToggle.next().css('display', 'block');
```

do this:

```
$(this).toggleClass("active").next().css('display', 'block');
```

or:

```
$(this).toggleClass("active");
$('.active').next().css('display', 'block');
```